# AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'NoReturn' while installing Jupyter Notebook using pip (python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter-lab, python-venv

I am using python 3.6. I installed Jupyterlab using pip command in my virtual environment but when I type "Jupyter Notebook" to open it, I get the error:

```py
def _failing_new(*args: t.Any, **kwargs: t.Any) -> t.NoReturn:
AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'NoReturn'
```

---- *Currently installed libraries in my virtual environment are* : ----

```
 argon2-cffi==20.1.0 async-generator==1.10 attrs==21.2.0      
   backcall==0.2.0 bleach==3.3.1 certifi==2021.5.30 cffi==1.14.6      
   charset-normalizer==2.0.3 colorama==0.4.4 decorator==5.0.9      
   defusedxml==0.7.1 entrypoints==0.3 idna==3.2      
   importlib-metadata==4.6.1 ipykernel==5.5.5 ipython==7.16.1      
   ipython-genutils==0.2.0 jedi==0.18.0 Jinja2==3.0.0 json5==0.9.6      
   jsonschema==3.2.0 jupyter-client==6.1.12 jupyter-core==4.7.1      
   jupyterlab==2.3.1 jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2 jupyterlab-server==1.2.0
   MarkupSafe==2.0.1 mistune==0.8.4 nbclient==0.5.1 nbconvert==6.0.7    
   nbformat==5.1.3 nest-asyncio==1.5.1 notebook==6.4.0 numpy==1.19.5    
   packaging==21.0 pandas==0.25.3 pandocfilters==1.4.3 parso==0.8.2     
   pickleshare==0.7.5 prometheus-client==0.11.0 prompt-toolkit==3.0.3   
   pycparser==2.20 Pygments==2.9.0 pyparsing==2.4.7 pyrsistent==0.18.0  
   python-dateutil==2.8.2 pytz==2021.1 pywin32==301 pywinpty==1.1.3     
   pyzmq==22.1.0 requests==2.26.0 Send2Trash==1.7.1 six==1.16.0      
   terminado==0.10.1 testpath==0.5.0 tornado==6.1 traitlets==4.3.3      
   typing-extensions==3.7.4.3 urllib3==1.26.6 wcwidth==0.2.5      
   webencodings==0.5.1 zipp==3.5.0
```

Most are installed with jupyterlab itself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you are using Python 3.6.0; this attribute was only added in Python 3.6.2 ([reference](https://bugs.python.org/issue28556)). I would highly recommend updating your Python installation to at least Python 3.6.13 (there were many security fixes since 3.6.0 release), and ideally switching to Python 3.7.x or 3.8.x if possible.